# Does ASP.NET have a dictionary URL notation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In an ASP.NET WebApi, you can do the following:

```
public class Something { 
    public int Foo;
    public string Bar;
}

public class SomethingController : ApiController {
    public string Get(Something s) {
        return "whatever";
    }
}
```

The URL to that will be:

```
"http://myapi/Something?s.Foo=123&s.Bar=abc"
```

Note the: **s.Foo=** and **s.Bar=** notation.

It is also possible to pass arrays in a URL like this:

```
"http://...?array=1&array=2&array=3"
```

Is there any notation for dictionaries? One like this for example:

```
public string Get(Dictionary<string, string> d)
```

Also, what are the other possibilities for data structures in an ASP.NET URL?

I can't find any documentation to that.

**EDIT**

The duplicate has nothing to do with what I asked.

Comment: WebForms binding is similar to MVC binding.  Have the parameter name match your data, e.g., call the dictionary `s` instead of `d`, because the binder matches on parameter/property name.  Arrays are the same: if you want a string array called 'myStrings', your parameter and querystring values should all be named the same. The binder will put those querystring values into the parameter.

Comment: Unless a valid, WebAPI-centric duplicate question is provided, this should be reopened. (I'm sure there is one, but the current one does not seem valid.)